# How to connect 2.2" LCD to nanopi(an arm-based board) with Debian Jessie OS?

Tags: linux, debian, lcd

I have a nanopi-m1 board that has Debian Jessie OS and 40 GPIO pins similar to RaspberryPi.Also a 2.2" TFT LCD with SPI interface compatible.

This is the LCD (http://www.elecfreaks.com/wiki/index.php?title=2.2S%22_TFT_LCD:_TFT01-2.2S).

How can I using it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have solved the problem here and it worked good:
https://github.com/notro/fbtft/issues/428

Briefly:

1.I did install Armbian that it has fbtft support by default in it's kernel.

2.I found that the GPIO pin numbers in nanopi is different from raspberry pi and changed them

3.I did follow this tutorial and it worked good for me: http://marcosgildavid.blogspot.no/2014/02/getting-ili9341-spi-screen-working-on.html

Comment: Could you summarise what exactly fixed the problem in your answer?

Comment: 1.I did install Armbian that it has fbtft support in it's ketnel.
2.I found that the GPIO pin numbers in nanopi is different from raspberry pi and changed them
3.I did follow this tutorial and it worked good for me: http://marcosgildavid.blogspot.no/2014/02/getting-ili9341-spi-screen-working-on.html